# Docker container with Postgres has no variables set when pushed with GitHub Actions

Tags: postgresql, dockerfile, github-actions

I try to push my Postgres container with Github Actions to Docker Hub. I created .yml file, Dockerfile and have all secrets inside my repo:

Secrets
[image]

Dockerfile

```
FROM postgres:latest

ENV POSTGRES_USER=${POSTGRES_USER}
ENV POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
ENV POSTGRES_DB=${POSTGRES_DATABASE}
```

Action file (.yml):

```
name: Build and Push Docker Image to Docker Hub

on:
  push:
    branches: [ "production/*" ]

jobs:
  push_to_registry:
    name: Push Docker image to Docker Hub
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Check out the repo
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      - name: Set up Docker Buildx
        uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v2

      - name: Log in to Docker Hub
        uses: docker/login-action@f054a8b539a109f9f41c372932f1ae047eff08c9
        with:
          username: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_USERNAME }}
          password: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_PASSWORD }}

      - name: Extract metadata (tags, labels) for Docker
        id: meta
        uses: docker/metadata-action@98669ae865ea3cffbcbaa878cf57c20bbf1c6c38
        with:
          images: /* my image path */
      - name: Build and push Docker image
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v2
        with:
          context: .
          push: true
          file: ./dockerfiles/postgres-amp-api/Dockerfile
          labels: ${{ steps.meta.outputs.labels }}
          tags: ${{ steps.meta.outputs.tags }}
          secrets: |
            "POSTGRES_USER=${{ secrets.DOCKER_POSTGRES_API_USER }}"
            "POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${{ secrets.DOCKER_POSTGRES_API_PASSWORD }}"
            "POSTGRES_DATABASE=${{ secrets.DOCKER_POSTGRES_API_DB }}"
```

It was all working when I was putting plain text db, user and password inside Dockerfile, but for some reason when I do it with current approach, I can see in Docker Desktop that my variables are empty:

[image]

and I get this error on container startup:

```
Error: Database is uninitialized and superuser password is not specified.
       You must specify POSTGRES_PASSWORD to a non-empty value for the
       superuser. For example, "-e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password" on "docker run".

       You may also use "POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust" to allow all
       connections without a password. This is *not* recommended.
```

Do I miss anything? Is there any syntax error that I am not aware of?

Comment: You are trying to set env vars dynamically but you haven't set it in the docker context. see https://www.baeldung.com/ops/dockerfile-env-variable#dynamic_values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable in Dockerfile will not be resolved until you pass them using build-args.

You dockerfile should look like

```
FROM postgres:latest
ARG POSTGRES_USER=postgres
ARG POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
ARG POSTGRES_DATABASE=postgres

ENV POSTGRES_USER ${POSTGRES_USER}
ENV POSTGRES_PASSWORD ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
ENV POSTGRES_DB ${POSTGRES_DATABASE}
```

and action

```
...
...
...
      - name: Build and push Docker image
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v2
        with:
          context: .
          push: true
          file: ./dockerfiles/postgres-amp-api/Dockerfile
          labels: ${{ steps.meta.outputs.labels }}
          tags: ${{ steps.meta.outputs.tags }}
          build-args: |
            POSTGRES_USER=${{ secrets.DOCKER_POSTGRES_API_USER }}
            ....
```

reference https://www.baeldung.com/ops/dockerfile-env-variable#dynamic_values

Comment: Yes, defining `ARG`s, `ENV`s and changing `secrets` to `build-args` helped. I mark this as correct answer. Thank you.